# Profiling with Visual Studio, large Inclusive sample percent on closing or opening bracket of function? c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, profiling

Here's a link to a picture of what I'm talking about.

[image: Profiling]

Does this mean that 6.5% of program time is spent ending this function? Would making it inline help with things like this? You can't see it in the picture, but the function is void with no return. I've always been a bit confused with what exactly the profilier means with inclusive sample percent. Microsoft's [guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) seems slightly outdated and is really just a brief overview of features.

Assembly:
[image: Assembly]

Comment: Perhaps this is a total time spent in this function.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, that's not it. There are a number of other functions where the opening and closing brackets are at 0.1% (or nothing at all) and there are very large %'s spent inside the function. This large percent on closing happens very rarely in my program which is why i'm curious. The total is 9.1% for this function.

Comment: Well. Function epilog is very short and could not use that much time. Perhaps this is a time spent in destructors of local objects. Open assembly code and check what exactly happens after the last `_mm_prefetch` call.

Comment: That's a great idea thanks, I'll google how to do that. If you have any good resources off the top of your head about how to go about doing that it'd be appreciated.

Comment: Set breakpoint on the closing bracket then run your program. When it reaches breakpoint press `Ctr+Alt+D` or go to the menu Debug->Windows->Disassembly

Comment: Cool! Having done that, i'm having trouble differentiating which assembly lines apply to bInfo.sideToMove = !; and which are the ones slowing the program down. Would everything that's in the 6.1% be happening before the closing bracket? There's some assembly after as well.

Comment: I think it would be better if you post actual assembly code in your question.

Comment: Okay it's posted!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153834/discussion-between-ari0nhh-and-max-c).

Answer (score 0):

I found your question as I wondered the same thing. The best I can come up with is that the time at the beginning of the function is the time to set up the stack before the first instructions associated with your code are executed and the time at the end is the time to clear the stack. So this might include copying function variables creating stack variables and calling their constructors and the opposite at the end.